# Applying axioms to inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, axioms

For example I'm supposed to prove that if $xy>0$, then $x>0$ and $y>0$, or $x<0$ and $y<0$. I'm supposed to do this using only these axioms:

1. $(x+y)+z=(x+z)+y$
2. $x+y=y+x$
3. $x+0=x$
4. There exists an $x'$ such that $x'+x=0$.
5. $(x*y)*z=(x*z)*y$
6. $x*y=y*x$
7. There exists element $1$ such that $1\neq 0$ and $x*1=x$
8. There exists an $x'$ such that $x'*x=1$
9. $x*(y+z)=x*y+x*z$
10. $x>0, x<0, or x=0$

My first idea was to just use axiom $10$ and apply that to both $x$ and $y$ and keep showing that contradictions exist, but in that case it seems like I'm only using axiom $10$ at the beginning and just using logic from there instead of using ONLY axioms. Any ideas on how I'd apply these to inequality proofs like this one?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have any axioms relating the order $<$ to the operations $+$ and $\ast$?

Comment: Upon looking online, I see that there are, but my assignment says using only axioms 1-10, in which case there are none that even mention inequalities as you can see

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are missing some axioms, because without more axioms about the behavior of the order relation, here's a simple counterexample.

Start with the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with their ordinary addition and multiplication operations, which satisfy axioms 1--9. Define the relation $<$ on $\mathbb{R}$ as follows: $x>0$ for all $x \ne 0$ except for $x=-1$; define $-1<0$. Extend over all other pairs which do not involve $0$ in any arbitrary way you please. Axiom 10 is satisfied. But we have $-1 \cdot 2 > 0$, but $-1 < 0$ and $2>0$, which violates what you are supposed to prove.

Comment: I suspected similarly, but this is an assignment and my instructor only gave us these axioms to work with. However, looking at your counterexample, why is -1*2>0?

Comment: @user333673: Because $-1 \cdot 2$ is not $-1$, and applying the definition of $<$.

Comment: @Hurkyl I see. I was not even aware of that definition. The consensus seems to be that I'm missing axioms. Would you agree that the problem is impossible using only these given axioms?

Comment: @user333673: Yes; this post proves it is impossible, by giving a nonstandard definition for $<$ that satisfies the given axioms, but does not satisfy the theorem you are asked to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is an element $t$ other than $1$ and $0$, and suppose $t>0$ and $1<0$. Then $1t=t$ by axiom 7, but now $1t=t>0$ while $1<0$ and $t>0$ which contradicts what you are trying to prove.